# A strange crash when call posix_memalign in my C++ project about a reference to a long list

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, out-of-memory

We meet a very strange problem when our system begin to run.
In simple terms, when a reference to a long list of structures appears in my code, the project crashes in calling `posix_memalign()`.

**The name of list is 'conf' below.**

```
int CChunkManager::block_load(const std::list<ChunkConfInfo>& conf, CChxdMain* proc)
{
    void* read_buf;
    printf("%s %s %u\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__); // for debug
    posix_memalign(&read_buf, 4096, 4096); // corruption
    free(read_buf);
    // ...
```

The size of the list is 5700+, and the structure is not large.

```
struct ChunkConfInfo
{
    unsigned _devid;
    std::string _file;
    uint64_t _binlog_start;
    unsigned _binlog_size;
    uint64_t _data_start;
    unsigned _data_size;
    unsigned _is_parity;

    ChunkConfInfo(){}

    ChunkConfInfo(const ChunkConfInfo& r)
        : _devid(r._devid), 
        _file(r._file), 
        _binlog_start(r._binlog_start), 
        _binlog_size(r._binlog_size), 
        _data_start(r._data_start), 
        _data_size(r._data_size),
        _is_parity(r._is_parity)
    {
    }

    ChunkConfInfo& operator= (ChunkConfInfo& r)
    {
        _devid = r._devid;
        _file = r._file;
        _binlog_start = r._binlog_start;
        _binlog_size = r._binlog_size;
        _data_start = r._data_start;
        _data_size = r._data_size;
        _is_parity =  r._is_parity;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

We initialized this list in function `LoadChunkRawConf`, and give reference to the list into function `block_load`.

```
int CChxdMain::load_chunks() {

    int ret = _cfg.LoadShmConf();
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = _cfg.LoadChunkRawConf(_cfg._chunk_raw_conf);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = CChunkManager::_.block_load(_cfg.chunk_conf, this);
    return ret;
}
```

Finally, it crashes in `block_load` when calling `posix_memalign`.

The most strange thing is that when the size of the list is 4000 or smaller, it works. But the size of stack is 8M enough, so we can not find the reason.

Comment: It is hard to tell based on your description. It seems like you are missing something in your description. Posix `posix_memalign` followed by `free` should be OK assuming you don't use `read_buf` afterwards. Does  `posix_memalign` return 0 for success? And `posix_memalign` takes a byte count, not an element count. I also think you need to call in-place new after you acquire the memory. Otherwise the block is uninitialized. Finally, `std::list` is not contiguous.

Comment: The application crashes when the function posix_memalign be called. So posix_memalign can not return a value.

Comment: `conf` isn't used at all in the example you show, so I can't see how changing its size could affect the program.  Please post a [mcve] with actual code that crashes.